# Communicate from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, nic

I have two laptops running Ubuntu 12.04 on which I want to build a (virtual) network using VMware Workstation. The first step is to communicate between the hosts by using an crossover cable.

I have set the NIC´s on the same netwerksegment as following: 192.168.1.1
                                                              192.168.1.2

Do I have to set an route-definition? And how can I do this, so they refer to each other and I can ping?

Answer (score 0):

Make a classic client server program i.e. socket programming for linux.
To learn how to do it you can click [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

Comment: No I did this before but I guess it was then already regulated by the Virtual Machine.